# How to get the N nearest entries to the median in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, series, median

For a Pandas Series:

```
ser = pd.Series([i**2 for i in range(9)])
print(ser)
0     0
1     1
2     4
3     9
4    16
5    25
6    36
7    49
8    64
dtype: int64
```

The median can be grabbed with `ser.median()`, which returns `16`.  How can the *N* entries around the median be grabbed?  Something like:

```
print(ser.get_median_entries(3)) # N == 3; not real functionality
3     9
4    16
5    25
dtype: int64
```

Comment: what if `n==2` ? would you take 9 16 or 16 25 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the abs difference between each value and the median and use `sort_values()`:

```
ser[abs(ser - ser.median()).sort_values()[0:3].index]
#4    16
#3     9
#5    25
#dtype: int64
```

If you want it as a function, where `n` is an input variable:

```
def get_n_closest_to_median(ser, n):
    return ser[abs(ser - ser.median()).sort_values()[0:n].index]

print get_n_closest_to_median(ser, 3)
#4    16
#3     9
#5    25
#dtype: int64
```

You will probably have to add some error checking on the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

logic for your problem, you can implement this logic according to your problem.

```
data={j:i**2 for j,i in enumerate(range(0,9))}
median=16

def nearby_values(data,median,depth):
    #subtract each value from median and then slice only three from sorted
    return list(map(lambda x:x[1],sorted([(abs(median-j),j) for i,j in data.items()])[:depth]))
print(nearby_values(data,median,3))
```

output:

```
[16, 9, 25]
```